# Crashes When ReBind-Reload LongListMultiSelector

Tags: windows-phone-8, crash, bind, multi-select, longlistselector

My Windows Phone application crashes when creating a new instance of binded list

BindedList Change:

```
OsyId = Response.recordedBills.Count > 50 ? new List<RecordedBillDetailViewModel>(Response.recordedBills.Take(50)) : new List<RecordedBillDetailViewModel>(Response.recordedBills);
```

MultiSelector:

```
<toolkit:LongListMultiSelector ItemsSource="{Binding OsyId}" x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="longList" EnforceIsSelectionEnabled="{Binding EnforceSelectionEnable}" Margin="0,0,10,0" SelectionChanged="LongListMultiSelector_SelectionChanged" IsSelectionEnabledChanged="LongListMultiSelector_IsSelectionEnabledChanged" MaxHeight="600" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

Crash Report:

```
   {System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(IntPtr ptr, String name, CValue[] cvData)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodPack(IntPtr objectPtr, String methodName, Object[] rawData)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_TransformToVisual(UIElement element, UIElement visual)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.TransformToVisual(UIElement visual)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListMultiSelector.ApplyItemsState(State state, Boolean useTransitions)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListMultiSelector.OnIsSelectionEnabledChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListMultiSelector.OnIsSelectionEnabledPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(DependencyProperty dp, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListMultiSelector.set_IsSelectionEnabled(Boolean value)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListMultiSelector.UpdateIsSelectionEnabled()
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListMultiSelector.OnSelectionChanged(IList removedItems, IList addedItems)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListMultiSelector.OnSelectedItemsCollectionCleared(Object sender, ClearedChangedArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListMultiSelector.SelectedItemsList.ClearItems()
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection1.Clear()
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListMultiSelector.OnItemsSourceChanged(Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListMultiSelector.OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged(Object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(DependencyProperty dp, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RefreshExpression(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SendDataToTarget()
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourcePropertyChanged(PropertyPathListener sender, PropertyPathChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.PropertyPathListener.RaisePropertyPathStepChanged(PropertyPathStep source)
   at System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.RaisePropertyPathStepChanged(PropertyListener source)
   at System.Windows.CLRPropertyListener.SourcePropertyChanged(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Data.WeakPropertyChangedListener.PropertyChangedCallback(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at Windows8.Common.Helpers.NotifyPropertyChanged.OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
   at Windows8.Common.Helpers.NotifyPropertyChanged.SetProperty[T](T& storage, T value, String propertyName)
   at Windows8.Common.ViewModels.BillPaymentViewModel.set_OsyId(List`1 value)
   at Windows8.Common.ViewModels.BillPaymentViewModel.<InitiateBillRequestToRecordedBill>d__ee.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Windows8.Common.ViewModels.BillPaymentViewModel.<SetRecordedBillsAction>d__71.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Windows8.Common.ViewModels.CompanyMenu.<BillPaymentSubScreenAction>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Windows8.Common.Helpers.DelegateCommandAsync.<System.Windows.Input.ICommand.Execute>d__0.MoveNext()}
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new instance try to clear and add items to the list. It might help solve the problem. This is assuming `OsyId` is a `ObservableCollection<RecordedBillDetailViewModel>`

```
var itemsToAdd = Response.recordedBills.Take(50); // Take 50 is fine even when the response does not have 50 items. Need not add a contion for it.
OsyId.Clear();
foreach(var item in itemsToAdd)
    OsyId.Add(item)
```

Thanks,
Shubhan

Answer (score 0):

As @Shubhan said, it must bind by only `ObservableCollection` because **it uses the `INotifyCollectionChanged` event**. Lists are using `IPropertyChangedEvent`. There is an event casting in `LongListSelector` like that:

```
xxxxx as INotifyCollectionChange;
```

and it is using the `xxxx` event for rebinding or resizing transactions.

Thanks.